# is it possible to set vscode editor.rulers from a batch file or somesuch

Tags: visual-studio-code

as title, from time to time I want to make temporary changes to the ruler settings in vscode.

ideally I'd like to do this without faffing with settings.json, alternatively is it possible to set editor.rulers for a specific file in settings.json?

Comment: What's your goal / motivation for wanting this? Would it solve your problem to do this on a per-workspace basis by using the `.vscode/settings.json` workspace settings file? Or to combine that with wrapping the setting in a language block so it only applies to particular languages? Ex. `"[markdown]": { "editor.rulers": [] },`.

Answer (score 0):

if you've got sed, this is dangerous but effective. can't help thinking there's something clever and javascripty that could be done within vscode itself.

```
$ type rerule.bat 
@echo off 
if (%1)==("") echo bad argument & goto :eof 
copy /y %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json reruleScrewedTheSettings.json > nul 
if (%1)==() sed "/editor.rulers/s#\[.*\]#\[\]#" %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json > TMP 
if not (%1)==() sed "/editor.rulers/s#\[.*\]#\[%1\]#" %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json > TMP 
copy /y TMP %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json > nul 

$ rerule "17,101,115,160,313"
```